# How to enforce developers to use square over than curly brackets?

Tags: angular

I want to enforce developers in my application to use `[]` instead of `{{}}` in element attributes.

for example this code should cause an error (in the build/serve/lint time ):

```
<mycomponent id="{{i}}">
```

the current code is

```
<mycomponent [id]="i">
```

How I do that?

Comment: The above suggestion is the best xD. If it's not in your control, just add a **linter** rule. Make sure all code satisfy them before adding to the codebase.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://rangle.io/blog/custom-tslint-for-angular/

Comment: as I know you can change the default interpolation symbole throw the 'interpolation' metadata of your component but if you want to void the interpolation way the best approach is just to tell them

Comment: I would just enforce it during a code review

Answer (score 10):

As commented, one of the possibilities would be to create a custom TSLint rule and add severity to force developers when compiling throwing the proper errors.
You will have a tslint.json in your project for all the core rules and custom ones.

Please, check here how to write a custom rule: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/

In other matters be aware that TSLint is being deprecated and ESLint would be its substitute.

Answer (score 3):

Teach them, be nice and set good examples.